# (Flutter/Dart) String with line break get error: Syntax Error: Unterminated string.: Undefined location

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

Hello I am using https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter trying to enter the String with line break the value from String is like this:

Example:

```
String value = "Hello\nHow are you\n";

String mutation = 
return """
        mutation{
        submitForm(input: {
            content: "$value"
        }) {
            success
        }
      }
    """;
```

However after I insert String that contain '\n' the GraphQL call is error and I got:

> GraphQL Errors: Syntax Error: Unterminated string.: Undefined location

Is there any way to enter string with line break for GraphQL in flutter/dart? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example used to add a todo.

```
static String addTodo =
      '''mutation addTodo($title: String!, $isPublic: Boolean!) {
 action: insert_todos(objects: { title: $title, is_public: $isPublic }) {
    returning {
     id
     title
     is_completed
   }
 }
 }''';
```

If you need any extra information about GraphQL in flutter I recommend you to take a look at [this guide](https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/flutter-graphql/introduction/) because after you have finished it you will be able to do anything you want.